# How to implement check and set or Read - Update ACID transaction in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike, distributed-transactions

I have a usecase where I have data in Aerospike and now that data required frequent updates, but under a transaction, following ACID. The documentation doesn't clearly show how to achieve it: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/go/usage/kvs/write.html#read-modify-write

Answer (score 2):

It should simply require you to set 'EXPECT_GEN_EQUAL' in the write policy, so that the generation of the record is checked prior to applying the write transaction. If the generation doesn't match, you will get an error back and the server will tick the [fail_generation](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/index.html?show-removed=1#fail_generation) stat. The generation is an internal simple counter metadata on a per record basis that gets incremented every time the record is updated.

You of course would need to then first read the record in order to get its current generation.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't describing what your operations are. Are you aware that in Aerospike you can do multiple operations on the same record in a single transaction, all under the same record lock? This is the operate() method in  all the language clients. For the Go client, it's documented at https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#Client.Operate